# How do I change the icon of a python file for others to see?

Tags: python, windows

I want to change the icon of a python-file which I created.
The thing is that I want the icon to be visible, if I transfer this file to other computers aswell.
Advice would be strongly appreciated. 
RCADE

Answer (score 0):

In windows, all files with `.py` extension have the python icon. You cannot change that for a particular py file. It is, after all, just a textual file. Where would the icon be read from?

What you could do is create a different kind of file, e.g. an `.exe` file which runs your `.py` file in Python interpreter. Executable files can have custom icons.

Then, you would probably also want to create an installer which installs the executable, one or more python source files, possibly even the python interpreter itself.

Comment: "What you could do is create a different kind of file, e.g. an .exe file which runs your .py file in Python interpreter. Executable files can have custom icons."
Could you tell me how to do that please?